# How can I reset my SetInterval when going to next question?

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm building a quiz and now have the problem when going to the next question that my timer is doing weird.... it jumps for example from 4 to 9 and then to 3 but I want it to go to 10 again and just countdown to 0 and jump to the next question. Could someone explain me this? Or is it better to use SetInterval? It would be appreciated if you could help me out with this!

```
var currentQuestion = 0;
var currentCount = 0;
var maxCount = 3;
var totalScore = 0;

function displayQuestion() {
  var question = allQuestions[currentQuestion].question;
  var showQuestion = $(document).find(".question-full");

  var showQuestionImage = $(document).find(".questions-img");
  var questionImage = allQuestions[currentQuestion].questionImg;

  var numAnswers = allQuestions[currentQuestion].responses.length;
  var answerList = $(document).find(".answers-buttons");

  /// SCORE
  var scoreCounter = $(document).find(".scoreCounter");

  $(showQuestion).text(question);
  $(showQuestionImage).html(questionImage);

  $(answerList).find("li").remove();
  $(scoreCounter).find("span").remove();
  $('.result-container').find("h2").remove();
  $('.result-container').find("img").remove();
  $('.result-container').find("a").remove();

  $('<span>'+ totalScore +'</span>').appendTo(scoreCounter);

  var answers;
  var score;
  for(var i = 0; i < numAnswers; i++) {
    answers = allQuestions[currentQuestion].responses[i].text;
    score = allQuestions[currentQuestion].responses[i].score;
    $('<li><button class="nextButton" data-score="'+ score +'" type="button">'+answers+'</button></li>').appendTo(answerList);
  }

  nextQuestion();


  $(".nextButton").on("click", function () {
    var score = $(this).data('score');
    IncreaseScore();

    currentQuestion++;

    totalScore += score;

    if (currentQuestion < allQuestions.length) {
        displayQuestion();
    } else {
      $('.after-container').fadeIn('slow');
      $('.content').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });
}


function nextQuestion() {
  var tijd = 10;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    tijd--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = tijd;
    if(tijd == 0) {
      currentQuestion++;
      displayQuestion();
      console.log(tijd);
      clearInterval(tijd);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function IncreaseScore() {

  currentCount++;

  if (currentCount > maxCount) {
    currentCount--;
  }
}
```

Comment: clearInterval(interval)

Answer (score 1):

Really close! Just your interval is not being cleared, as there is the wrong reference:

```
function nextQuestion() {
  var tijd = 10;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    ...
      clearInterval(tijd);
    ...
  }, 1000);
}
```

should be

```
function nextQuestion() {
  var tijd = 10;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    ...
      clearInterval(interval);
    ...
  }, 1000);
}
```

Your implementation is all fine, just you would have had all the intervals still running until 0 and updating `#countdowntimer` with whatever one fired last in the second.